# DropDown - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dropdown

Sou iniciante em ASP.NET MVC e preciso criar um DropDown num formulário de cadastro de veículos onde possibilite escolher somente um condutor relacionado ao veículo que esteja previamente cadastrado no banco de dados (criado via Entity Framework). Meu código atualmente está assim:

**Condutor**

```
public class Condutor
{
    public int CondutorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Matricula { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CPF { get; set; }
}
```

**Veiculo**

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Modelo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Marca { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AutorizacaoFilter] // filtro de autorizacao, localizado na pasta "Filters"
public class VeiculoController : Controller
{
    // atributos do controller para acesso ao banco de dados
    private VeiculoDAO dao;

    // construtor da classe
    public VeiculoController(VeiculoDAO dao)
    {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Veiculo> lista = dao.Lista();
        return View(lista);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult IncluirVeiculo(Veiculo veiculo)
    {
        dao.IncluirVeiculo(veiculo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");   
    }


    public IActionResult Cadastro()
    {
        var model = new Veiculo();
        return View(model);

    }


    // remove um veículo, através do seu id cadastrado na tabela do banco de dados
    public IActionResult RemoverVeiculo(int id)
    {
        dao.RemoverVeiculo(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    // localiza um veículo pelo seu Id e o exibe na View "Ver Cadastro", para ser editado
    public IActionResult VerCadastro(int id)
    {
        Veiculo veiculo = dao.BuscaVeiculoPorId(id);
        return View(veiculo);
    }


    // edita o registro do veículo e reflete as alterações no BD
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditarVeiculo(Veiculo veiculo)
    {
        dao.AtualizaCadastro(veiculo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult BuscaVeiculo(string termo)
    {
        IList<Veiculo> veiculos = dao.BuscaPeloTermo(termo);
        return View("Index", veiculos);
    }

}
```

**View**

Ignorem o enum, foi só para fazer teste, enquanto não consegui resolver o DropDown

```html
@model Veiculo

<div class="container">
 <br />
 <h2>Cadastrar veículo</h2>
 <br />

 <form class="form-horizontal" action="/Veiculo/IncluirVeiculo" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Modelo:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo" style="max-width:50%" placeholder="Ex: Palio, Gol, Corsa, etc" name="modelo" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Marca:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" style="max-width:50%" placeholder="Ex: Chevrolet, Honda, Nissan, etc" name="marca" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Tipo:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10" style="max-width:43%">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.Tipo,
   new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Tipo))),
   "-- Escolha uma opção --",
   new { @class = "form-control"})
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Limpar dados</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Resolvendo esse exemplo, a idéia é utilizar outros dropdowns também, entre Models diferente. A dificuldade atual minha foi que, como a View é fortemente tipada em Veiculo, não consegui criar esse "vínculo" com a classe Condutor.

No caso, como eu poderia criar esse tipo de DropDown, via Entity Framework utilizando LINQ e LAMBDA?

Comment: Veiculo e condutor se relacionam?

Comment: Não há relacionamento entre eles

Comment: Você precisa gravar `CondutorId` na tabela `Veiculo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a ViewBag para passar uma listagem da `Controller` para a `View`.
E para fazer o relacionamento entre `Veiculo` e `Condutor` teria que criar uma propriedade `Condutor` na classe `Veiculo`.

Ficaria assim:

Na classe `VeiculoController` na action `Cadastro` (se essa for mesmo a action da sua view de cadastro), você carrega a ViewBag com a lista de *Condutores*.

```
public IActionResult Cadastro()
{
    var model = new Veiculo();

    var condutores = dbContext.Condutor.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = c.CondutorId.ToString(),
            Text = c.PrimeiroNome
        });

    ViewBag.Condutores = condutores;

    return View(model);
}
```

Para você recuperar o `Condutor` selecionado e salvar isso no `Veiculo`, precisa ter relacionamento do `Condutor` no `Veiculo`.

```
public class Veiculo {

public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Modelo { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Marca { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Tipo { get; set; }

public Condutor CondutorVeiculo { get; set; }
```

}

E finalmente na `view` ficaria assim:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CondutorVeiculo.CondutorId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Condutores, new { @id = "ddlCondutores", @class = "form-control" })
```

Veja se isso funciona para você.

Comment: Após as implementações acima, o DropDownListFor funcionou corretamente, listando os condutores e atualizando automaticamente caso seja cadastrado um novo. Porém,  gerou alguns problemas no CRUD de veículos em geral. Ao escolher a opção desejada do DropDown, ocorre uma SQL Exception: 'SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Condutor' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." O que poderia ser? (vou inserir a estrutura das tabelas em uma resposta).

Comment: Acho que tem haver com algum mapeamento da tabela Veiculo no Entity. A tabela Veiculo foi criada através do Migrations na classe Veiculo? Parece que quando você tenta inserir um registro na tabela Veiculo, o entity está tentando inserir um registro na tabela Condutor. E se você buscar o Condutor (pelo Id selecionado no dropdownlist) e atribuir este no objeto Veiculo que você está tentando incluir?

Comment: Nesse caso aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509608/ef-code-first-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-when tinha haver com a configuração do entity.

Answer (score 0):

O DropDown funcionou corretamente, sendo adicionadas novas opções na lista conforme os condutores são cadastrados. Porém, vários problemas no CRUD de Veículo. Um deles é a exception **'SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Condutor' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."** ao cadastrar um novo veículo. Abaixo, seguem as tabelas (criadas via migrations no Entity Framework):

**Tabela Veiculos**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Veiculos] (
[Id]                        INT NOT NULL,
[Modelo]                    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Tipo]                      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Marca]                     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[CondutorVeiculoCondutorId] INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Veiculos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Veiculos_Condutor_CondutorVeiculoCondutorId] FOREIGN KEY ([CondutorVeiculoCondutorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Condutor] ([CondutorId])
```

);

**Tabela Condutor**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Condutor] (
[CondutorId]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Matricula]                 INT            NOT NULL,
[PrimeiroNome]              NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[UltimoNome]                NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[CPF]                       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[CondutorVeiculoCondutorId] INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Condutor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CondutorId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Condutor_Condutor_CondutorVeiculoCondutorId] FOREIGN KEY ([CondutorVeiculoCondutorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Condutor] ([CondutorId])
```

);

Comment: Tente colocar o atributo  [NotMapped] na propriedade CondutorVeiculo.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes, aparentemente deve ser algum problema das migrations. Tabela Veiculo foi criada via Migration também. Mesmo colocando [NotMapped], ele aparece outro erro **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'FleetCar.dbo.Veiculos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.**. Vou verificar quanto a recriação dos modelos de entidades para ver se resolve o problema.